# Pronunciation of: I got a text from Ashley

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

When we pronounce the phrase: *I got a text from Ashley* we usually stress the content words (as long as we don't want to make a contrast of course):

> I GOT a TEXT from ASHley.

So as long as there's no special emphasis or contrast I think the preposition *from* can be reduced and pronounced with a schwa sound. It doesn't need to be stressed. Am I right?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, and since there is no special emphasis on "from", it does not need to be stressed.